# c - scandir, memory fault core dumped error

Tags: c, scandir

I am trying to list information about files in a specified directory but I am getting a Memory Fault Core Dumped error. 
List Directory Method:

```
int listdir(char *path) {

struct dirent **dirlist;
int n;  
char *fullpath;
n = scandir(path, &dirlist, NULL, alphasort);

while (n--) {
    strcpy(fullpath, path);
    strcat(fullpath, dirlist[n]->d_name);
    (void)printfinf(fullpath);      

    free(dirlist[n]);
}
free(dirlist);

return 0;
}
```

Printfinf Method - this method works fine, prints out information about the file

```
int printfinf(char *path) { 

struct stat info;
struct passwd *pswd;
lstat(path,&info);          
pswd = getpwuid(info.st_uid);
char *modestr = mode2str(info.st_mode, getuid(), getgid());
char *timestr = time2str(info.st_mtime);

printf("%s %s %10lld %s %s\n", modestr, pswd->pw_name, info.st_size, timestr, path);

char c = modestr[0];

if(c == 'd')
    return FTYPE_DIR;
else if(c == 'f')
    return FTYPE_REG;
else if(c == 'e')
    return FTYPE_EXE;
else if(c == 'l')
    return FTYPE_LNK;
else return FTYPE_OTH;  

}
```

Comment: Hello! Why did you remove the code from your question? Now it's totally unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for the target path string, you didn't.

If you type `man strcpy` in your terminal, then you would know that the first parameter of `strcpy()` should point to preallocated memory, changing your code to use arrays like this

```
char fullpath[PATH_MAX];
```

would solve the problem.

**WARNING**: DO NOT IGNORE WARNINGS!!!

It is very clear that you either ignore them or silence them, ignoring the return value of a function is wrong (*most of the time*), you should check what the function returned to perform good error handling.

Also, don't use `strcat()`. Instead do this (*after changing the suggested above*)

```
int length;
length = snprintf(fullpath, sizeof(fullpath), "%s/%s", path, dirlist[n]->d_name);
if ((length >= sizeof(fullpath)) || (length == -1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Either, there is no room for the "
                    "target string or an error occurred\n");
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, I am very new to c so it's all a little weird, it was working for me then all of a sudden it stopped so I got worried

Comment: @AhamadBoali That is called undefined behavior, and it happens in [tag:c]. It could work sometimes, but then suddenly ... oh! sorry, that's what you said :)